# Is there a ReSharper template to generate a basic method?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

I'm new to ReSharper and am surprised that there isn't a template defined for

```
public void MethodName(<params>)
{

}
```

I realize I could create one, but I would have thought this would have been part of the standard product.  Perhaps I'm missing some other shortcut?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not aware of any such default template, but as you pointed out it's terribly easy to write:

```
public void $METHODNAME$($PARAMS$)
{
    $END$
}
```

However, I'm more that a tiny bit perplexed that you're interested in making all your methods both public and void **by default.**

Comment: Good point.  Probably they should be private an the return type should be parameterized.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up with:

```
private $RETURN_TYPE$ $METHODNAME$($PARAMS$)
{
    $END$
}
```

I tied it to the single letter "m".

Comment: I wonder what do you productivity gain do you have from such a template? You still have to type everything except few parentheses and braces. And this is better done with Complete Statement (Ctrl-Shift-Enter).

Comment: Auto formatting, decide things in a different order, smart suggest and having the visibility options listed in a CSV.

Answer (score 1):

My version:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
private $RETURN_TYPE$ $METHODNAME$($PARAMS$)
{
    $CLIPBOARD$
    $END$
}
```

Notice: In Template Editor you can insert macro for each `$FIELD$`. For example: "Clipboard content" macro for `$CLIPBOARD$`.

Comment: Does this ever get annoying with random clipboard contents being included? I normally use the refactor menu when I have existing code.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Can be two templates, eg. `Empty Method`, `Method from Clipboard`